# Weird bug with Action Bar / Action Bar Sherlock, some kind of second shadowy bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I seem to be having trouble getting rid of this second bar, shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbPm.png 
(cant post images)

It doesn't show when in landscape view, or on my 10" tablet in portrait view.

I've tried the following fixes:

```
 android:uiOptions="none"
```

in my manifest

Here is the code for my items:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/profile"     
    android:title="User Profile"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" ></item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This second bar looks like the Tab action bar, try to put `getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);` somewhere in your code (in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` for example).

Also be sure you have the latest version of ActionBarSherlock installed.

Comment: Problem is I'm actually using the support action bar, so I need it enabled.

Comment: Thank you, I realise I had action.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
from previously using tabs!